# Turn 2 coordinates vectors into matrix, matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I have 2 vectors, one call X and enother calls Y.
In X I have the x coordinate, and in Y the y coordinates.
The first coordinate in X and the first in Y give a point, and so on..
The numbers in each vectors are float, and can be negative and positive.(-29.3, 14.2)
If I make plot on them I'm getting a green square.

```
plot(X,Y,'g');
```

What I want is to turn both vectors into 1 matrix, and if I will do `imshow(Matrix)`
I will get the same square image.

Doing this:

```
Matrix = [X;Y;];
```

Didn't work. It just draw somthing green on the screen.
Hope I was clear enough.
Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shlomi, you need to use [`hist3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html).

For example:

```
m=hist3([X' Y'],nbins)
```

just select the number of bins `nbins` appropriately so you'll have the grid resolution you want.  Then `imshow(m)` will work.